# Issue with UNION Query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, content-management-system, union

I'm trying what seems to be a simple union query for two tables in my database though I am unable to retrieve a successful array result. It should be noted that each table has different columns and that I'd like to create a virtual result (promo AS origin [for the result pulled from the 'venpromo' table] && vacation AS origin [for the result pulled from the 'vacation' table]) in order to sort the results into different array structures. I've looked everywhere and UNIONS are all using different syntax. Thank you all in advance!

```
<?php
    require_once('includes/config.php');

    $event_query = "SELECT *, promo AS origin FROM venpromo
    UNION 
    SELECT *, vacation AS origin FROM venpromo 
    ORDER BY popularity DESC";
    $event_result = mysql_query($event_query, $connection);
    while ($event = mysql_fetch_array($event_result)) {
        if ($event['origin'] == "promo") {
            $event_array[] = array(
                'id' => $event['id'],
                'title' => $event['calname'],
                'start' => $event['sdate'],
                'end' => $event['edate'],
                'color' => "red",
                'url' => "http://www.norrisportal.com/bulletinpost.php?id=" . $event['id'] . "&hashkey=akdULjsjyUpYyTzOT7"
            );
        } elseif ($event['origin'] == "vacation") {
            $event_array[] = array(
                'id' => $event['id'],
                'title' => $event['reason'],
                'start' => $event['vacstart'],
                'end' => $event['vacend'],
                'color' => "blue"
            );
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($event_array);

?>
```

When visiting the page to view the results, I see 'null'.

Comment: Can you give the columns and their data type for both table? what error are you getting?

Comment: Please, add table structure to your question. This information is critical when talking about UNION queries

Comment: This link shows screenshots of the structures from PHPMyAdmin 
[Table Structure](http://i48.tinypic.com/2yod9nm.jpg). Please excuse my ignorance, I'm new to UNION and thanks again for the help in advance!

Comment: @AjithSasidharan - I've submitted a link to the Table Structure. Thanks!

Comment: Am I the only one not seeing the columns you are querying in your table structure?

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Put the columns names explicitly rather than *, and make sure the number of columns and data types match for the same column in each select.**

I have added some dummy columns to match the number and data types in both the tables and also changed the order of the columns.

try this sample way ::

```
select 
id,
uid,
approval,
vacstart,
vacend,
reason,
'dummy1' col1,
'dummy2' col2,
'dummy3' col3,
curdate() col4,
'dummy4' col5,
'dummy5' col6,
'dummy6' col7,
'dummy7' col8,
promo AS origin
from vacation
union
select
id,
venid,
authid,
sdate,
edate,
authname,
tags,
title,
calname,
date,
intro,
body,
sum,
sortdate,
vacation AS origin
from venpromo;
```

Comment: +1 because the answer is theoretically correct; still, I can't see where those `promo` and `vacation` columns are in the tables